# openpyxl -> Write a slice of cells to new workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm generating summary sheets for large data sets by snipping the top 20 rows from 150-2000+ source Excel documents and compiling them together in one doc. I am hoping to cut out some compiling time. Currently using python's openpyxl module to load and collect the segments I need, but what I'd like to do is write a slice//segment of cells to a new Workbook all at once, rather than iterate over each cell individually. Suppose I'm defining a slice as:

```
sheetSlice=sh[f"A1:{chr(colcount-1+65)}{min(rowlim,rowcount)}"]
```

*Please excuse the ugliness of how I set up the slice notation*

Is there any way to take this slice//group of cells and write it to a new openpyxl.Workbook() object all at once? I was unable to find any documentation regarding this type of operation. Thanks! xoxo

Comment: There is this link for optimised reading and writing using openpyxl: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html

Comment: You might also try switching to win32com to automate the Excel application, as that allows you to set the value of a range of cells from an array in one hit. Maybe read the files using the lazy evaluating openpyxl optimised functions and write the new file using automation.

Comment: @DS_London thanks! I'll be sure to check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to access it cell by cell. However, you can use list comprehension and `ws.iter_rows()` to write a function that neatly copies and pastes a range of data.

```
import openpyxl as op


def flatten(t):
    return [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]


def excel_copy_paste(
    ws_copy, ws_paste, row_min, row_max, col_min, col_max, paste_row=1, paste_col=1
):
    # Copying your range
    copy_range = flatten(
        [
            [cell.value for cell in row]
            for row in ws_copy.iter_rows(
                min_row=row_min, max_row=row_max, min_col=col_min, max_col=col_max
            )
        ]
    )
    paste_range = flatten(
        [
            [cell for cell in row]
            for row in ws_paste.iter_rows(
                min_row=paste_row,
                max_row=paste_row + row_max - row_min,
                min_col=paste_col,
                max_col=paste_col + col_max - col_min,
            )
        ]
    )
    for cell_copy, cell_paste in zip(copy_range, paste_range):
        cell_paste.value = cell_copy


# Workbook, worksheets
wb = op.load_workbook("EXAMPLE.xlsx")
ws = wb["All data"]
ws_new = wb["Sheet1"]

# Copy/paste
excel_copy_paste(ws, ws_new, row_min=1, row_max=5, col_min=1, col_max=7)

# Save
wb.save("EXAMPLE.xlsx")
```

Note that this won't preserve format.

Comment: Hadn't thought of it like that. Very cool-- thanks!

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complicated with lots of nested loops.

Comment: @Charlie there is probably a much neater way of doing it, this was just an example